# introjs opening and highlighting modal window md-dialog

Tags: angularjs, json, intro.js, mddialog, angularjs-material

I'm using introjs and am wondering if there's a way for it to open up a modal window and highlight it as part of the tour.  How would that look in the JSON object?

Currently, I have a button that opens up the tour onclick:

```
<md-button class="md-accent md-raised" ng-click="startIntro();"><i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Take a Tour</md-button>
```

My tour steps are defined in a JSON object in the client controller:

```
$scope.startIntro = function(){
        var intro = introJs();
          intro.setOptions({
            steps: [
              { 
                intro: "Welcome to your Portal!  Here's how to navigate through this site."
              },
              {
                element: document.querySelectorAll('#small-btn')[1],
                intro: "Take a minute and fill out your Questionnaire.  It will prepare you for your first day."
              },
              {
                element: '#twitter',
                intro: "Follow us on social media!",
                position: 'top'
              } 
            ]
          });
          intro.start();
      };
```

As for my modal window, I'm using a md-button that brings up a md-dialog box:

```
<md-button id="small-btn" class=" btn1" ng-click="showAdvanced($event)" >    
        <md-tooltip md-direction="right">Questionnaire</md-tooltip>
        <md-icon ng-if="!data.sysID" ng-style="{'background-color':'#F44336'}" class="circle-border md-60">assignment</md-icon>
        <md-icon ng-if="data.sysID" ng-style="{'background-color':'#4CAF50'}" class="circle-border md-60">assignment_turned_in</md-icon>
      </md-button>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onbeforechange` event in intro.js (documented here: https://introjs.com/docs/intro/api/) to open the modal upon entering that step, and close the modal on leaving the step.

```
intro.onbeforechange(function(targetElement) {
  if (angular.element(targetElement).attr("id") === "step3") {
    $scope.openModal();
  }
  else {
    $scope.closeDialog();
  }
});
```

You have to be careful that when you setup the introjs object using the `setOptions` call that your step actually exists in your template. To achieve this, you can use the "Pre-rendered Dialog" settings explained on the `md-dialog` demo (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog). This essentially means that your dialog exists in the DOM whether the modal is actually showing or not. You open this like so:

```
$mdDialog.show({
  parent: angular.element(document.body);,
  targetEvent: $event,
  contentElement: "#modaldialog"
});
```

where `#modaldialog` is a div encapsulating your `<md-dialog>`.

Here is an example fiddle showing how this might work: https://plnkr.co/edit/r3Sd2Ti8pKn33A9DJ7R0